# When I run a program in Android Studio it gives me special error

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, runtime-error, emulation

When I run the program the emulator is not showing anything and gives me these errors:

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... √  Built
> build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk. cmd: Can't find service:
> activity Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
> Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install
>
> adb: failed to install
> C:\Users\asher\StudioProjects\i_am_rich\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk:
> cmd: Can't find service: package Error launching application on sdk
> gphone64 x86 64.

What is the solution of the above problem? I tried a lot to solve this problem but could not.